# Every convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, cauchy-sequences

Today, my teacher proved to our class that every convergent sequence is a Cauchy
sequence and said that the opposite is not true, i.e. Not every Cauchy
sequence is a convergent sequence. However he didn't prove the second statement. Is there an example or a proof where Cauchy
sequence is not convergent?

Comment: @ClementC. The question didn't mention that spaces are not complete. In that case I withdraw my comment.

Answer (score 2):

In the metric space $(0, 1]$, the sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ given by $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ is Cauchy but not convergent.

Comment: But isn't $1/n$ convergent because in limit $n\rightarrow{\infty}$, $1/n\rightarrow{0}$

Comment: That is the point: it converges in $[0,1]$ (or $\mathbb{R}$), but *not* in $(0,1]$ (the space it is defined in).

Answer (score 2):

You will not find any real-valued sequence (in the sense of sequences defined on $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual norm), as this is a *complete* space. (By definition, a metric space is complete if... every Cauchy sequence in this space is convergent.)

But you **can** find counter-examples in more "exotic" metric spaces: see, for instance, [the corresponding section of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence#Counter-example:_rational_numbers). One of the classical examples is the sequence (in the field of rationals, $\mathbb{Q}$), defined by $x_0=2$ and
$$
x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n}{2} + \frac{1}{x_n}
$$
for $n \geq 0$. It can be shown this sequence is Cauchy; but it converges to $\sqrt{2}$, which is not a rational: so the sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is Cauchy  (in $\mathbb{Q}$), but not convergent (in $\mathbb{Q}$).

(Note that the same sequence, if defined as a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, *does* converge, as $\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{R}$).